# Is Synco G1 (A1) mic input (TRS) stereo or balanced?

Tags: microphone, wireless

So the Synco G1 wireless microphone transmitter has a TRS jack 1/8 mic input.

Does this TRS mic input stand for **balanced** or **stereo** audio?

I have searched the web, but I can't find any confirmation about this...

Comment: Hi La Page PT and welcome. Please use the **Add a comment** box below the answer if you wish to request more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the user's manual, it's for the included lav mic; therefore it's a balanced, mono, mic input.